# django template html how to use filter with a context value as a string argument of that filter

Tags: html, django, templates, django-filter

i'm try to do smthing like this:

`{% for i in list %} <td style="background-color: {{color_rule|get_item:i}}">{{i}}</td> {% endfor %}`

where:
`def get_item(dictionary, key): return dictionary.get(key)`

please help

Comment: What's the problem that you're facing? Could you show us what `list` and `color_rule` look like?

Comment: `"color_rule": {
            'c':'rgb(87,213,255)',
            'a':'rgb(182,83,248)',
            'g':'rgb(163,196,60)',
            't':'rgb(243, 100, 96)',
        },`, and  list = "CAGCCAGACCACAGGCCAGACATGACGTGGAGGCAAGCGGCCACAACGTGGAGGTGGA"

Comment: Thanks, please see my answer - your list and dict keys aren't the same case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary keys are lower case letters but the list are all uppercase - keys are case sensitive so nothing is being returned. Change your list to all lower case or your dict keys to uppercase and it will work.

Referring to the comment with additional context:

```py
color_rules = {
   'c':'rgb(87,213,255)',
   'a':'rgb(182,83,248)',
   'g':'rgb(163,196,60)',
   't':'rgb(243, 100, 96)',
},
list = "CAGCCAGACCACAGGCCAGACATGACGTGGAGGCAAGCGGCCACAACGTGGAGGTGGA"
```

As an aside, you should avoid naming variables with python functions, i.e. `list()` - also the list isn't actually a list but a string. Something like `color_string` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

```
{% for key, i in list.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ i}}
{% endfor %}
```